# Entity Framework Core is slow - how do I make it faster?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Retrieve records from database and assign it to an object.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
var itemsData = _context.Items;

for (int i = 0; i < itemsData.Count(); i++)
{
    _Response.Items.Add(new Models.Items
        {
            Name = itemsData.ToList()[i].Name,
            ....
            Created = (DateTime)itemsData.ToList()[i].Created,
            Updated = (DateTime)itemsData.ToList()[i].Updated
        });
}
```

**Note**: There are less than 1000 records and already it's noticeability slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `ToList` on every iteration, which executes the SQL query against the database every time. Do this 1000 times and no wonder it's slow.

Just call `ToList` once and then `foreach` the result:

```
var itemsData = _context.Items.ToList();

foreach (var item in itemsData)
{
    _Response.Items.Add(new Models.Items
    {
        Name = item .Name,
        ....
        Created = (DateTime)item.Created,
        Updated = (DateTime)item.Updated
    });
}
```

Comment: EFCore is still not that fast, but I think it's the best I could do?

Comment: @001 there's other performance gains to be had. I believe at a certain point it's actually quicker to recreate the DBContext and save on each iteration. This stops the change tracker from getting too big which can slow down requests significantly.

Comment: +1 for Steve's comment - I've had the same experience. For bulk updates the speed improvements you get from ditching the db context and then recreating it every 100 iterations or so can be massive.

Comment: Another perf thing you can do If you are just putting these right into the response then you don't need tracking.  Could use `_context.Items.AsNoTracking().ToList();` and EF wont spend time putting the tracking stuff in place.

Comment: @DavevanHerten also true, especially for this case when you're just reading the details, not updating.